# How to get the first item in a SelectList to be empty in ASP.NET MVC project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have looked online for a solution, but the solutions I have found are applicable to code that has been implemented quite differently to mine.

My dropdownlist is populated with a List called SelectionList, this is populated in my controller.

```
        SelectionList= (db.Items.ToList())
```

The view is as followed:

```
                @Html.Label("Selection:", htmlAttributes: ...)
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Table.SelectionID, new SelectList(Model.SelectionList, "SelectionID", "ItemName"), new { @class = ... })
                </div>
```

There are no issues with displaying the selectionlist, however I would like the first item to be blank so that the dropdownlist initially does not display any items.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: If I have a look on the overloads, actually the empty option should be "ItemName" in your case...see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor(v=vs.118).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Table.SelectionID, new SelectList(Model.SelectionList, "SelectionID", "ItemName"), "", new { @class = ... })
```

That third param with the empty string specifies the option label.